# How to create dask dataframe from CSV file stored in HDFS(many part files)

Tags: hdfs, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to create dask dataframe from HDFS file(csv). The csv file stored in HDFS has many part files.

On read_csv api call:

```
dd.read_csv("hdfs:<some path>/data.csv")
```

Following error occurs:

```
OSError: Could not open file: <some path>/data.csv, mode: rb Path is not a file: <some path>/data.csv
```

In fact /data.csv is directory containing many part files. I'm not sure if there is some different API to read such hdfs csv.

Comment: Can you ensure that your path-string looks like `"hdfs:/some/path/data.csv/*.csv"` (note the '/' after the colon and the glob pattern)?

Comment: Thanks mudrant, glob pattern worked :)

Comment: @mdurant: If I may ask in this thread itself, dask is not able to read parquet(on hdfs and does not have metadata) files saved by spark. Is there any fix for that.

Comment: Yes you can: explicitly pass the list of files, e.g., from running hdfs.glob('/path/parquet/*.parq'). Also, spark does have an option to write the metadata file.

Answer (score 2):

Dask does not know which files you intend to read from when you pass only a directory name. You should pass a glob string uses to search for files or an explicit list of files, e.g.,

```
df = dd.read_csv("hdfs:///some/path/data.csv/*.csv")
```

Note the leading `'/'` after the colon: all hdfs paths begin this way.